# .NET SOAP serialization, omit/remove enclosing tags for generic list<t>

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, soap, wsdl

I need to call a Web Service, created by someone else, from a .Net C# application.

The web service requires me to send a list of items ("articles"), without enclosing them in a parent element. This is a simplified illustration of the "desired" look of the call:

```
<body>
  <info>something</info>
  <moreinfo>something else</moreinfo>
  <article>
    <articleno>123</articleno>
  </article>
  <article>
    <articleno>456</articleno>
  </article>
</body>
```

On my end, the articles is a generic List<Article>, and my call to the web service tends to contain something looking more like this:

```
<body>
  <info>something</info>
  <moreinfo>something else</moreinfo>
  <articles><!-- parent element -->
    <article>
      <articleno>123</articleno>
    </article>
    <article>
      <articleno>456</articleno>
    </article>
  </articles><!-- parent element end -->
</body>
```

The WSDL file from the web service is corrupted, so I've hade to manually create a working subset of the functions in it that I need. Using that "hand coded" WSDL I add a Service Reference using Visual Studio 2013.

I have been trying to solve the problem by modifying the WSDL, and by modifying the code that is created by Visual Studio when adding the service reference, but so far I haven't succeeded.

I've bee trying various attributes for the list parameter, such as XmlElement, XmlIgnore, MessageHeaderArrayAttribute and others, but to be honest I don't know how they work or which ones could actually be useful in this scenario.

Can the WSDL be altered to make Visual Studio's auto generated code create the correct output when calling the web service? (Preferred solution)

Or is there a way to force soap serialization to produce the list of articles without an enclosing element? (Acceptable solution)

Here is a simplified version of the relevant (as far as I can tell) portions of the WSDL

```
<xsd:element name="PriceRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="info" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="moreinfo" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="articles" type="tns:ArrayOfArticlestructObj"  />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
...
<xsd:complexType name="ArticlestructObj">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="articleno" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="otherinfo..." type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="ArticlestructObj" type="tns:ArticlestructObj" />
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfArticlestructObj">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ArticlestructObj" nillable="true" type="tns:Articlestruct" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="ArrayOfArticlestruct" type="tns:ArrayOfArticlestruct" />
```

I am a noob on WSDL as well as on StackOverflow, so please excuse me if this question is hard to read.

Comment: What do you mean, the WSDL is corrupted?

Comment: @John Saunders: The WSDL file that is generated by the web service contains errors; it can not be parsed by Visual Studio, nor by a couple of other programs that I have tried reading it in. It contains perhaps 100 methods, and I only need to use two of them, so I've managed to pick out the pieces I need and rid them of errors manually.
One of the errors is that it refers to a complex type which is not defined in the WSDL. There could be loads of errors, I gave up on trying to fix it entirely and focused on the part I need.